# What is the standard tool to display a polyhedron given xyz coordinates?

Tags: polyhedra, visualization

I have a file containing xyz coordinates of vertices of a polyhedron. What tool can open xyz file, display faces, edges and vertices as well as rotate/zoom the polyhedron? Preferably something that doesn't require fancy scripting for this task. Is there one standard tool (like Matlab), or there are other tools.

I am looking for result similar to gif images here:

http://www-wales.ch.cam.ac.uk/~wales/CCD/Thomson/table.html

XYZ file itself looks like this

4.71e-01 8.66e-01 1.70e-01
-5.07e-01 8.45e-01 1.70e-01
1.85e-10 7.49e-11 1.00e+00
-4.71e-01 -8.66e-01 1.70e-01
..

Comment: You might be interested in [VRML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML) or [X3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D)

Comment: Of course you can do it easily with Matlab ?

Comment: Or [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/?src=google&420). Or [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/).

Comment: Using Matlab or Matematica for this is like trying to get a  thimble of water from a fire hydrant. I only need to rotate and zoom objects. I used JMol, but it treats everything as molecules, so it only shows vertices and edges. Will try heavy weight apps, since those are main tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Antiprism](http://www.antiprism.com/) is a suite of programs which can visualize and manipulate polyhedra. I think it meets the lightweight, standalone criteria you're looking for.

The viewing program, antiview, deals with files in [OFF format](http://www.antiprism.com/programs/off_format.html) (see also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_(file_format))), which is also shared by other programs. This format also requires the specification of faces, because the polyhedra need not be convex.

To use your files with only the coordinates of the vertices, you can add two header lines:

```
OFF
# 0 0
```

replacing `#` by the number of vertices. Then use `conv_hull` from Antiprism to create an OFF file for the convex hull. You can do e.g.

```
conv_hull -o poly.off verts.off
```

to create a new file with all the faces, then use `antiview poly.off` to view it.  Or

```
conv_hull verts.off | antiview
```

to pipe straight into antiview.

In fact, if you do not add the two header lines suggested above, `conv_hull` will assume it is a list of vertex coordinates, and it will work anyway, but print a warning.